# AWS CDK - How to add multiple http methods to the same resource

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

How can I have a standard endpoint of `/spaces` but different lambda functions for different HTTP methods?

I was hoping I'd be able to use a helper function

```
addResource(path: string, method: HttpMethods, lambda: lambda.Function) {
  const lambdaIntegration: LambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(lambda, { proxy: true });
  const resource: Resource = this.restApi.root.addResource(path);

  resource.addMethod(method, lambdaIntegration, {
    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
  });

  return resource;
}
```

And just call it for each resource I want to add

```
// POST - spaces
gateway.addResource('spaces', HttpMethods.POST, new Function(this, 'droppixel-space-post', {
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
    code: Code.fromAsset(`${__dirname}/../lambda-fns/space-api/src`),
    handler: 'create.handler',
    environment: {
        TABLE: table.table.tableArn
    }
}))

// GET - spaces
gateway.addResource('spaces', HttpMethods.GET, new Function(this, 'droppixel-space-get', {
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
    code: Code.fromAsset(`${__dirname}/../lambda-fns/space-api/src`),
    handler: 'list.handler',
    environment: {
        TABLE: table.table.tableArn
    }
}))
```

This works well with just one resource, but adding additional will fail with

```
There is already a Construct with name 'spaces' in RootResource [Default]
```

Is there a proper pattern for how to do this nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `addResource` is performing `this.restApi.root.addResource(path)` each time you invoke the method, in your case twice, hence the error about the duplicate.

If you need to keep existing shape of the custom `addResource` method, you can verify whether the resource is already defined on given path via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.Resource.html#getwbrresourcepathpart. If the resource exists you will skip duplicate addition of the resouce.

Comment: I also get the same error.   public addCorsOptions(apiResource: apigw.IResource) {
    apiResource.addMethod(
      "OPTIONS",.   Any suggestions? Can you please more detail?